# Why am I getting an error when adding namespace (using WebMatrix.WebData;) in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webmatrix, websecurity

I want to use `WebSecurity.ChangePassword()` in my ASP.NET MVC project, for that I need to install the `WebMatrix.WebData` NuGet package.

I have already installed it, but in the namespace, I'm getting the error:

[image]